# Creating a worksheet from two existing worksheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy some columns data from two different sheets. Columns are not the same since this information comes from two different data bases.

The highlighted columns are the information I need to copy into the new Database:
[image]

In this database there are two green highlighted columns.
If there's id data on column "M" I take this if not I copy from column "F":
[image]

My code works. The problem is from the moment I load an important amount of data, Excel crashes.

```vb
Sub KPI()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Actuals")
Dim ws_omt As Worksheet: Set ws_omt = Sheets("OMT")

'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim wsResult As Worksheet: Set wsResult = Sheets("DB")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow_omt = ws_omt.Cells(ws_omt.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on the orders column

For i = 2 To LastRow
    NextRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws.Range("C" & i & ":D" & i).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("B" & NextRow)
    ws.Range("L" & i & ":L" & i).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("D" & NextRow)
    ws.Range("F" & i & ":F" & i).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("H" & NextRow)
    ws.Range("N" & i & ":N" & i).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("E" & NextRow)
    ws.Range("O" & i & ":O" & i).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("F" & NextRow)
    ws.Range("X" & i & ":X" & i).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("G" & NextRow)
    wsResult.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = "Actuals"
    wsResult.Range("I" & NextRow).Value = "None"
Next
    
For i2 = 2 To LastRow_omt
    NextRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws_omt.Range("D" & i2 & ":D" & i2).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("C" & NextRow)
    ws_omt.Range("G" & i2 & ":G" & i2).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("G" & NextRow)
    ws_omt.Range("J" & i2 & ":K" & i2).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("E" & NextRow)
    
    If ws_omt.Range("M" & i2 & ":M" & i2).Value <> "" Then
        ws_omt.Range("M" & i2 & ":M" & i2).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("H" & NextRow)
    ElseIf ws_omt.Range("F" & i2 & ":F" & i2).Value <> "" And ws_omt.Range("M" & i2 & ":M" & i2).Value = "" Then
        ws_omt.Range("F" & i2 & ":F" & i2).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("H" & NextRow)
        wsResult.Range("J" & NextRow).Value = "1"
    Else
    wsResult.Range("H" & NextRow).Value = "None"
    End If
    
    ws_omt.Range("A" & i2 & ":A" & i2).Copy Destination:=wsResult.Range("I" & NextRow)
    wsResult.Range("A" & NextRow).Value = "OMT"
    wsResult.Range("D" & NextRow).Value = "None"
    wsResult.Range("B" & NextRow).Value = 1
Next
    
LastRow_db = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For i3 = 2 To LastRow_db
    If wsResult.Range("A" & i3 & ":A" & i3).Value = "OMT" Then
        wsResult.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=3, Header:=xlYes
        'RemoveRups just working removing from bottom-up if conditions dont look to work
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you can say `wsResult.range("B2:B" & lastrow).value=ws.range("b2:b" & lastrow).value`  no need to copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions below.  You do not need to loop for most of the copying, and as Nathan points out you could switch to assigning `Value` directly as that would be faster, as long as you don't also need to copy formatting.

```vb
Sub KPI()

    Const DATA_START_ROW As Long = 2 'use constants for fixed values
    
    Dim LastRow As Long, i3 As Long, rngIds As Range,
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws_omt As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim allData As Range, rw As Range, mVal, fVal, rwDest As Range

    'don't combine declarations and assignments on the same line...
    Set ws = Sheets("Actuals")
    Set ws_omt = Sheets("OMT")
    Set wsResult = Sheets("DB")

    'speed up
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


    '----first sheet--------
    'all the input data
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set allData = ws.Range("A" & DATA_START_ROW & ":A" & LastRow).EntireRow
    'next destination row
    Set rwDest = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    
    'you're copying all of the data so no need to go row-by-row
    allData.Columns("C:D").Copy rwDest.Columns("B")
    allData.Columns("L").Copy rwDest.Columns("D")
    allData.Columns("F").Copy rwDest.Columns("H")
    allData.Columns("N").Copy rwDest.Columns("E")
    allData.Columns("O").Copy rwDest.Columns("F")
    allData.Columns("X").Copy rwDest.Columns("G")
    'fixed values
    rwDest.Columns("A").Resize(allData.Rows.Count).Value = "Actuals"
    rwDest.Columns("I").Resize(allData.Rows.Count).Value = "None"
    
    '----next sheet--------
    'next input data
    LastRow = ws_omt.Cells(ws_omt.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set allData = ws_omt.Range("A" & DATA_START_ROW & ":A" & LastRow).EntireRow
    'next destination row
    Set rwDest = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    
    'copy whole columns first
    allData.Columns("A").Copy rwDest.Columns("I")
    allData.Columns("D").Copy rwDest.Columns("C")
    allData.Columns("G").Copy rwDest.Columns("G")
    allData.Columns("J:K").Copy rwDest.Columns("E")
    'fixed values
    rwDest.Columns("A").Resize(allData.Rows.Count).Value = "OMT"
    rwDest.Columns("D").Resize(allData.Rows.Count).Value = "None"
    rwDest.Columns("B").Resize(allData.Rows.Count).Value = 1
    
    'only loop where you need to
    For Each rw In allData.Rows
        mVal = rw.Columns("M").Value
        fVal = rw.Columns("F").Value
        If Len(mVal) > 0 Then
            rw.Columns("M").Copy rwDest.Columns("H")
        ElseIf Len(fVal) > 0 And Len(mVal = 0) Then
            rw.Columns("F").Copy rwDest.Columns("H")
            rwDest.Columns("J").Value = "1"
        Else
            rwDest.Columns("H").Value = "None"
        End If
        Set rwDest = rwDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row
    Next rw
 
    LastRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngIds = wsResult.Range("C" & DATA_START_ROW & ":C" & LastRow)
    For i3 = LastRow To DATA_START_ROW Step -1
        If wsResult.Cells(i3, "A").Value = "OMT" Then
            If Application.CountIf(rngIds, wsResult.Cells(i3, "C").Value) > 1 Then
                wsResult.Rows(i3).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    'reset
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: This was super useful! Macro takes around 30s to execute instead of crashing after 20m of compiling. I can still use a little help with the last part of code that you didn't touch. For this last part, Once all the data has been copy there could be duplicates, Column "C" let me verify this thanks to the order number. I want to remove the whole row if there's a duplicate value on column "C" and column "A" is = to "OMT". Thanks again !